# SQL statement not working - "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table which i am trying to return the Time and Productno columns for a specific date. When i try the following SQL command it returns the error: "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int'.
 I have research on forums and this is the way most people have been achieving a similar thing which is getting me puzzled.
The data types for the following fields are as follows: Date: date. Time: time(7). Productno: int.

```
SELECT        Date, Time, Productno
FROM            Products
WHERE        (Date = 07 / 09 / 2008)
```

Please could i be advised where i am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try using Date = '07/09/2008'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your date format is incorrect, it needs to be in quotes and rearranged slightly.

```
WHERE        (Date = 'Year-Month-day')
```

or rather

```
WHERE        (Date = '2008-09-07')
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried the above but i got the following error: "Invalid column name 'Date'. Invalid column name '2008-09-07'.

Comment: Date is a keyword in SQL, try putting quotes around it so you've got 'Date', see this article for further details http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html.  Also are you sure you've got the case of the column name right, should it be DATE or date perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

> (Date = 07 / 09 / 2008)

Here you dividing (int)7 by (int)9 and then by (int)2008. So `07 / 09 / 2008` is an integer result of some calculations.
In order to pass the date instead, you should put it into quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT Date, Time, Production
FROM Products
WHERE Date="2008-09-07"
```

Date must be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format